# Datepicker - no reaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to add datapicker to my project. I have followed a tutorial.

I have added the following code to the DatePickerReady.js file:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker(); 
});
```

I have added the following code at bottom of the head element in the Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml file.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have added this to Views\Home\Index.cshtml

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>

 @{
    string dts ="";
    if (Model != null)
    {
        dts = ((DateTime)Model).ToShortDateString();

    }
    @Html.TextBox("start", String.Format("{0:d}", dts), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
}
```

But when I focus/click the textbox it does nothing. The calendar doesn't appear. I'm not  getting any errors as well.

Any clue?

Comment: Could you check the html itself, does that `input` element has `datefield` class? Also, I assume jQuery is loaded correctly here?

Comment: The input element has datefiled class. I have installed datapicker with packetmanager and it occurs in my Script dir.

Comment: I actually asked about jQuery core (not jQuery UI one)... but never mind, it should probably give you an error here. Ok, what happens when you run this line - `$('.datefield').datepicker()` in console?

Comment: this will help you... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4

Comment: Follow my tutorial as @naveen suggests. If you can't get it working, download the completed sample and use F12 or firebug to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure you have included all your scripts, from the scripts you have posted I did not see jquery.js, also make sure that these scripts are indeed available i.e check thier paths.

Use firebug and find out if you are getting any console errors when you click on the dateTime textbox.

Next check if the class is being attached to html textbox input and the jquery call is also made, verify these.

Here is a simple step by step guide to using Datepicker in ASP.NET MVC 3 : [Introduction to jquery Date Picker in ASP.NET MVC](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-jquery-date-picker-in-asp-net-mvc/)

and I am very curious to know what does `DatePickerReady.js` do ?

Comment: Stupid me! I have indeed forgotten to include jquery... DatePickerReady.js  just registers datepicker for .datefield class :$(".datefield").datepicker(); . So I can keep all js scripts separately.